# How can I prevent injected JavaScript file reference code from running in my web page?

Tags: javascript, security, gmail, code-injection, javascript-injection

I don't know if it's possible to prevent the injection of a JavaScript reference file script into a web page, but I have seen sites that prevent you from running functions within the injected JavaScript reference file script unless it's JavaScript the page registers.  For example, I was able to inject 10 different JQuery scripts (with different versions) with different prefixes into Google Mail, but they do an excellent job of preventing you from executing certain JQuery commands.  There are a few that you can do, but only getting data (not setting data).. like $jquery171('html').html() (which is simply viewing the source for a page) for example.  How can I prevent other scripts from running in my web page like they do in Google Mail?  Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Do you want to prevent any Javascript or just some functions? A bit more details, please. And what's about gmail? Is your project related to that?

Comment: No, I'm just testing things on Google Mail and comparing them to other sites that are less secure to learn what you can and cannot do.  I am reading a book called Web Application Hackers Handbook and learning all kinds of things I'm not doing currently in my website.  Ultimately, I want to prevent someone from being able to change DOM elements in my website, or modify anything with JavaScript really, but have my JavaScript still work and do its job.  Things that all sites should implement as a best practice I guess.

Comment: And why not prevent complete javascript execution?

Comment: What do you mean by "complete JS execution"?  Does that include preventing JS execution of my page's JavaScript as well?  No, that should still function.  I don't want to turn off JavaScipt.  My website is a rich client application.

Comment: And why would you want to allow a user to execute custom js on your website?

Comment: @Cyber, exactly, why would I?  I would not want that.  I do NOT want custom/user/injected JS run on my website. I only want to allow the JS that renders in the page that originated from the web server to perform actions. I was expecting this to have a simple solution.

Comment: "No, I'm just testing things on Google Mail" You should be aware that what you are doing is illegal in the US. You don't have permission to perform penetration testing against google - even only for XSS.

Comment: Yah, I'm not being malicious at all.  I'm just trying to learn so others don't do it to my site.  I will read through that.  Thanks for the info.  In any case, I know some Google Chrome extensions that are able to manipulate the DOM of another site that are free to use--but they are just developer tools.  That is what I'm trying to prevent.  That's precisely what led me to ask this question.

Comment: Oh I get it now. You can't prevent user from loading your page with custom js; that being said if a user uses for example developer extension to manipulate DOM of the page it will only affect his browser and it displays the website on his computer... There are no security problem with that (unless you do something stupid like js authentication.). As said in the answer the problem occurs with XSS where the user is able to inject the js into the website so it may be executed by other users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vulnerability you are talking about is known as [Cross-site Scripting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_scripting); XSS for short. OWASP's [top ten project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_Ten) will also introduce you to other common attacks that you should be aware of as a web application developer.

To protect your own code against XSS, you must never print user-submitted data to the output HTML page as provided. You must encode the data in a context-dependent way, based on where in the HTML structure you are printing the userdata. Be aware that all data that does not come from your own program should be treated as untrusted - that includes HTTP headers, the URL, cookies, form POST data, and data from "outside" systems like databases.

See the [XSS Prevention cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) to get a good understanding of the basic principles of output encoding for HTML output.

Whether you think you are being malicious or not, what you doing against google is illegal. You are efefctively performing [partial] penetration testing to ascertain the vulnerability of their code to XSS. Whilst GMail may not mind this sort of thing too much -- they have to deal with malicious spam HTML emails, of course--, owners of some other websites most certainly do; People have been arrested and charged in the US for doing far less than what you have described.

Develop your own site to test against. You will not have permission to test the security of someone else's. Consider looking at projects like [WebGoat](http://owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_WebGoat_Project) and [Gruyere](http://google-gruyere.appspot.com) to give you an environment that you are legally allowed to attack.

Comment: Haha, I see that.  Good explanation though.  That was what I was looking for.  +1